# ImportError: No module named flask_toastr

Tags: python, flask, pip, toastr

I want to use Toastr, for showing non-blocking notifications in my Flask app. I already installed the package with pip :

```
sudo pip install Flask-Toastr
```

Here is the output of the installation

> Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Toastr in
>   /Users/****/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.5.2)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Flask in
>   /Users/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask-Toastr)
>   (1.1.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2 in
>   /Users/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask-Toastr)
>   (2.10.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in
>   /Users/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
>   Flask->Flask-Toastr) (7.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in
>   /Users/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
>   Flask->Flask-Toastr) (0.15.4)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in
>   /Users/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
>   Flask->Flask-Toastr) (1.1.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in
>   /Users/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
>   Jinja2->Flask-Toastr) (1.1.1)

Here is theimport statement:

```
from flask_toastr import Toastr
```

But when I run my script I have this ImportError. How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: And what does the import statement in your script look like?

Comment: Please post your script to check have you imported flask_toastr or not.

Comment: The problems is most probably in `sudo pip`. Never use `sudo` with `pip`. Unless you really understand why do you need `sudo`.

Comment: @phd No I also have this message in output of my console 'Successfully installed Flask-Toastr-0.5.2' but the code still crashs with the ImportError

Comment: This means that you've installed Flask-Toastr using `pip` for one Python and run import with another. Python packages are not global, every Python at your system has its own set. Install Flask-Toastr to your specific Python.

Comment: @phd  I installed the package for both version of my python distributions 2&3 using pip and pip3 and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your import statement I suspect you have used a '-' instead of an underscore in the import statement:
Try this:

```
from flask_toastr import Toastr
```

Comment: `import flask-toastr` would result in `SyntaxError`, not `ImportError`. So the import statement should be different.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your guess about `-` in import statement was wrong anyway.

Comment: You are right I missed the ImportError statement at the bottom. My apologies